# What does Salim say in his answer to Jodie?

Tags: beyond-two-souls

I don't think he speaks a fictional language, but I haven't any subtitles for his answers. Do I need to turn subtitles on to see a translation? Or are there any other sources of information?

Comment: Tvtropes mentions "If you happen to know Farsi, Chinese or Navajo, then you'll understand a good portion of what some characters are saying." Might be Farsi, then.

Comment: I'll put bounty on this question after a week or two. So, maybe then someone share translation of that dialogs.

Comment: It's not Farsi/Persian. I know the language but still didn't understand anything,My guess is,they might have tried to make it sound persian-ish but nah,it's not...also I know that "abi" means "my father" in arabic so......yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When he first met Jodie, he told her to back off in which later Jodie healed him he said ''My leg is renewed! I feel no pain! How did you do that!? My name is Salim''
Later when Jodie asked about the tower, Salim said ''Do you want me to take you to the fellows over there!? I can take you there, follow me, follow me!

Later when Jodie bids Good Bye to Salim, he says ''But I can't leave now! I got to keep helping you!'' but later says ''I will never forget about you''

Later when Jodie asks Aiden to possess his father, then kills everyone and gets Salims father killed in the process, Salim walks in and says ''Father, no! Don't leave me!''

''Why did you do that!?'' while he picks up the gun and points for Jodie'' Then he says ''Did you not think.....'' the dots is where I can't hear him correctly.

''Why did you kill my father!?'' ''I HATE YOU, I HATE YOU!''

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Salim was speaking in Arabic. I am a native Arabic speaker so I could understand just about everything he said. What he was saying is:
First when he met Jodie, He was telling her to not come any closer.

After she healed him, He said : "I can walk again! My leg! I don't feel pain anymore! I don't feel pain anymore! Witch! You are a witch! How could you do that? (in a good way).

After the fight, When Jodie was on the ground, He was asking her: "are you okay? did you get shot?"

When Jodie was staring at the tower, Salim was saying : "do you want to go there? to the tower of (couldn't hear name properly)? I can take you if you want! Come, Follow me!

When Jodie asked him if he was okay, He responded with : "i'm good i'm good. I didn't get hurt in any way"

When she was telling him she has to leave, he responded with : "I'm not leaving you! I can stay by your side! I can help you!" after that he said "for as long as I am alive, I will never forget what you've done for me

After Jodie killed Salim's father, He said : "Father! Father! No! Don't die my father! I need you don't leave me! don't leave me!" Before he shot Jodie, he said : "Why did you do that? I thought you were my friend" After he shot her, he said : "you killed my father! you killed my father! I HATE you I HATE you!"